# Мне нужен Node.JS хостинг!

Tags: javascript, node.js, хостинг

я не разбираюсь вобще, что такое vps не понимаю, 
мне желательно нужен хостинг на русском языке, чтобы я просто загрузил сайт
и он там сразу работал. 
ну и ещё чтобы домен можно было прикрутить, и платить недорого.

Comment: Ну так самое время разобраться, вы же на SO. Для установки NodeJS вам в любом случае будет предложен VPS/VDS.

Comment: ...либо кто-то не умеет искать

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот, к примеру [вот этот.](https://timeweb.com/ru/services/vds/)
Здесь сервер с панелью управления, и достаточно дешевый.

То есть, если вам нужна поддержка `node.js` вам в любом случае нужно будет покупать VDS. Об этом можно у них же и [прочитать.](http://timeweb.com/ru/community/questions/vozmozhnost-sozdaniya-nodejs-servera-1)

А домен тут не причем. Можно покупать в любом месте. Просто там, где будете покупать необходимо будет указать DNS хостинга.